# Extension of /@ operation

Tags: list-manipulation

If I want to extend this useful operation `/@` into a "matrix" version, say for example

```
(#1*{Cos[#2], Sin[#2]}) &/@
```

with one list for the first input and another for the second, giving a matrix result (list in list), how to realize it? And how to write it in a neat way if we want the diagonal terms in the matrix (so a single list).
Of course, we can do it easily by a loop, but it will be much cooler and neater to abbreviate it.

Example: example: (#1+#2) with input `{1, 2, 3}` and `{4, 5, 6}` for two slots, giving a matrix result `{{5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 8}, {7, 8, 9}}`. How to realize it? If we want a diagonal result `{5, 7, 9}`, how to realize it?

Comment: It would be easier if you showed a small input/output example

Comment: @Murta I don't think there is conceptual difficulty in understanding what I mean. Anyway here is one example: (#1+#2) with input {1, 2, 3} and {4, 5, 6} for two slots, giving a matrix result {{5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, 8}, {7, 8, 9}}. How to realize it? If we want a diagonal result {5, 7, 9}, how to realize it?

Comment: It would be more informative to others if you put your example in your question rather than in a comment.

Comment: Can you, please, clarify what you mean by the second point `"if we want a diagonal result"`? Do you want to be able to have that as the final output? Or is that a separate question?

Comment: @CATrevillian It is a different question. So what I mean is if we want to get the matrix as a final output (lists in a list), how to do it, and if we want to get the diagonal elements out (a single list), how to do it. Though these are two questions, I think the two operations can be done in slightly modifying the operation /@, so I just put them together.

Comment: `Outer[Plus, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]` gives the matrix result you're looking for.  `Outer[Plus, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]//Diagonal` gives the diagonal.

Comment: `f = Function[{x, y}, # + y& /@ x]; f[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]`

Comment: `{1, 2, 3} + {4, 5, 6}` also yields the indicated "diagonal result."